# Where can I find information about the yeast Saccharomyces Bayanus?

Tags: yeast, fermentation-temperature, wine

I was able to find plenty of information about the ale yeast [S. Cerevisiae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae) and lager yeast [S. Pastorianus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccharomyces_pastorianus), however information about the wine making yeast S. Bayanus appears to be more difficult to come by.  The article simply states that it is similar to the two.  Can anyone point me in the right direction regarding this yeast?  I'm looking for optimal brewing temperatures and anything else I can find about it.

Also, my reputation isn't high enough yet to include more than 2 links, but the information I found on S. Bayanus can be found on wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

According to [WineMaker Magazine](http://www.winemakermag.com/guide/yeast), there's two different strains from Vintner's Harvest.  Depending on which one you have, the following information should be everything you would need to ensure a proper fermentation:

```
Company             Yeast Name              Dry/Liquid  Strain #    Suggested Wine Styles                                                       Temp Range (°F)     Alcohol Tolerance (% ABV)/Flocculation
Vintner's Harvest   Saccharomyces Bayanus   Dry         CL23        Blush, Dry, Dry Whites, Sparkling Cuvée, Whites                             46-75°              18% High
Vintner's Harvest   Saccharomyces Bayanus   Dry         SN9         Aged Reds, Blush, Cider, Fruit Wine, Sparkling Cuvée, Whites, Young Reds    68-75°              18%
```

The above information also gives us some more information to go off of.  Assuming you have/plan on getting Vintner's Harvest yeast (I can't find any other lab that produces a strain by that name), here's their less technical information on the [CL23 strain](http://vintnersharvest.com/collections/wine-yeasts/products/vintners-harvest-wine-yeast-cl23) and the [SN9 strain](http://vintnersharvest.com/collections/wine-yeasts/products/vintners-harvest-wine-yeast-sn9).

Answer (score 1):

You can find information like fermentation temp and attentuation on different kinds of wine yeasts from the white labs homepage:
These are also the yeasts strains easily available for the homebrewer.

http://www.whitelabs.com/beer/homebrew/listings?style=3

Comment: or here: http://www.midwestsupplies.com/lalvin-wine-yeasts-5-grams-ec-1118-champagne.html